# jQuery load - Google visualizations page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a page with a few links and a div, on the same page that I will load other content into.
Some of that content is google visualizations charts.

Just as a test, I popped in the google line chart code. The page loads well on it's own, but when I try to load it into div (using jQuery), it doesn't work. Firefox says transfering data from google.com and does nothing, and IE 6 has a JS error saying `google`is undefined.

I don`t see why this would be a problem, but the page is on an intranet...if this helps troubleshooting.

Thanks for any and all help in advance..

Here is the code that loads the mainContent.html file into the div.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#A2W").click(function(){
                $("#loadContent").load("mainContent.html");
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

Contents of the mainContent.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["linechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 400);
        data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
        data.setValue(1, 2, 460);
        data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 860);
        data.setValue(2, 2, 580);
        data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 540);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, legend: 'bottom', title: 'Company Performance'});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the link so we can see and try to debug? :)

Comment: Just edited my question to include some code..

Answer (score 1):

Trying to stuff an entire HTML page into a div, which is already part of an HTML page, is a recipe for disaster. You'll finish up with the browser trying to work out what to do with all the things that are in the wrong place. Take the <head> element you just inserted, for example - should it try to move it up? It can't stay where it is, as that makes no sense. If it moves it under the original <html>, should it replace the existing <head> element?

Then what about the <body> It's already got a <body>; should it throw that away? Ah, but it can't because then it throws away the <body> inside the <html> inside the <div>...

Suffice to say that a browser's behaviour when you do something like this is completely undefined, and it probably just throws its hands up in despair and does nothing.

Comment: Wow.. that was very insightful... didn't think about all those aspects. I understand what you're saying, so I'll have to play around with the placement of the different snippets of code to be more logical..

Any other tips on this? Has anyone done this before? (I'm sure I'm not the first)